# base64 decoding of a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, base64

I have an encoded dataframe and I managed to get it decoded using following code in PySpark. Is there any simple way where I can have an additional column in the dataframe itself through Scala/PySpark?

```
import base64
import numpy as np
df = spark.read.parquet("file_path")
encodedColumn = base64.decodestring(df.take(1)[0].column2)
t1 = np.frombuffer(encodedColumn ,dtype='<f4')
```

I looked up multiple similar questions, but couldnt get them to work.

**Edit**:
Got it working with help from a colleague.

```
def binaryToFloatArray(stringValue: String): Array[Float] = {
val t:Array[Byte] = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringValue)
val b = ByteBuffer.wrap(t).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asFloatBuffer()
val copy = new Array[Float](2048)
b.get(copy)
return copy
}
val binaryToFloatArrayUDF = udf(binaryToFloatArray _)
val finalResultDf = dftest.withColumn("myFloatArray", binaryToFloatArrayUDF(col("_2"))).drop("_2")
```

Answer (score 9):

You have base64 and unbase64 functions for this.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=streaming#pyspark.sql.functions.base64

You could

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import unbase64,base64
    got = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "Jon"), (2, "Danny"), (3, "Tyrion")], ("id", "name"))

+---+------+
| id|  name|
+---+------+
|  1|   Jon|
|  2| Danny|
|  3|Tyrion|
+---+------+

encoded_got = got.withColumn('encoded_base64_name', base64(got.name))

+---+------+-------------------+
| id|  name|encoded_base64_name|
+---+------+-------------------+
|  1|   Jon|               Sm9u|
|  2| Danny|           RGFubnk=|
|  3|Tyrion|           VHlyaW9u|
+---+------+-------------------+

decoded_got = encoded_got.withColumn('decoded_base64', unbase64(encoded_got.encoded_base64).cast("string"))
# Need to use cast("string") to convert from binary to string


+---+------+--------------+--------------+
| id|  name|encoded_base64|decoded_base64|
+---+------+--------------+--------------+
|  1|   Jon|          Sm9u|           Jon|
|  2| Danny|      RGFubnk=|         Danny|
|  3|Tyrion|      VHlyaW9u|        Tyrion|
+---+------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Achilleus, I tried this before, but I think there is something different with the encoding, as the data is converted into a "binary" column. I tried to convert it to string, but resulting data is not what we are looking for. Column in question is an array of decimal values

Comment: Ah, gotcha. It works fine for string though. Can you post an example of the data you are trying to encode?